# Trouble running pyfirmata on raspberry pi 2 with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, importerror, raspberry-pi2, firmata

I am trying to run pyfirmata on my raspberry pi 2. I have it installed in here:

```
/home/pi/pyFirmata
```

But when I try to run the following code:

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')
analog_pin = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()
analog_pin.enable_reporting()

while True:
    reading = analog_pin.read()
    if reading != None:
        voltage = reading * 5.0
        print("Reading= %f\t Voltage= %f" % (reading, voltage))
        time.sleep(1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Arduino_Avoltage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
ImportError: No module named pyfirmata
```

I have read the "read me" file that was installed with the pyfirmata and the Arduino has standard firmata installed on it. I can't figure out what I did wrong. I need this to work with python 3, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Update: I just found out that this program will run in Python 2 if I change the first line to >>>import pyfirmata         is there a way to make this line work in python 3?

Comment: 1-Load as external lib(`imp`), 2-Use python 2.7, 3-Copy module in your work direcctory(`if additional libs not required`), etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put pyFirmata in *site-packages*:

```
/home/pi/Lib/site-packages/pyFirmata
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that turned out to be I had not completed my pifirmata setup:

sudo apt-get install python-pip python-serial 
sudo pip install pyfirmata    {yo note lower-case 'f'}

navigate to pyfirmata folder:  (probably cd pifirmata)
sudo python3 setup.py install

Comment: try: sudo pip3 install pyfirmata